# Select column value dependant on the value of another column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to produce a report and replace all NULL values in a 'NUMBER' column with a value between 1 and 10 dependant on the value of another 'VALUE' column and then total them up.  Some of 'NUMBER' have been included already, but some have not.  Basically, this is what I have -

```
**NUMBER**   **VALUE**    **DATE**
NULL         Apple        2012-08-01
NULL         Pear         2012-08-01
NULL         Banana       
NULL         Apple        2012-08-02
1            Apple        
2            Pear         2012-08-04
3            Banana       2012-08-04
```

What I need to produce is a report that shows something like this -

```
**NUMBER**    **VALUE**    **TOTAL**    **DATE**
1             Apple        3            2
2             Pear         2            2
3             Banana       2            1
```

The problem I have is that there is another COUNT within the SQL and I can't work out a way getting everthing to work together.  The current SQL is looks like this -

```
SELECT    NUMBER,
          VALUE,
          COUNT (NUMBER) AS TOTAL,
          COUNT (DATE) AS DATE

FROM      MY_TABLE

GROUP BY  NUMBER,
          VALUE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this query will return the totals you desire:

```
WITH ValueCount AS
(
   SELECT mt.Value, COUNT(1) AS Total
   FROM #My_Table AS mt
   GROUP BY mt.Value
)
, DateCount AS
(
   SELECT mt.Value, COUNT(1) AS DateTotal
   FROM #My_Table AS mt
   WHERE mt.MyDate IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY mt.Value
)
SELECT mt.Number, vc.Value, vc.Total, dc.DateTotal
FROM ValueCount AS vc
INNER JOIN #My_Table AS mt ON vc.Value = mt.Value
INNER JOIN DateCount AS dc ON vc.Value = dc.Value
WHERE mt.Number IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY mt.Number ASC;
```

I broke up totaling the Value from the Date because you were looking for different criteria.  If you do not like the look of the [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), you can accomplish this with multiple queries, or sub-queries as well.

When using a CTE, the preceeding query must end with a semi-colon.